# py.test does not find tests under a class

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm, pytest

I am trying to create test classes that aren't unittest based.

This method under this class

```
class ClassUnderTestTests:

    def test_something(self):
```

cannot be detected and run when you call py.test from the command line or when you run this test in PyCharm (it's on its own module).

This

```
def test_something(self):
```

same method outside of a class can be detected and run.

I'd like to group my tests under classes and unless I'm missing something I'm following the [py.test spec](http://pytest.org/latest/getting-started.html) to do that.

Environment: Windows 7, PyCharm with py.test set as the test runner.

Comment: You can customize pytest config to your needs with a pytest.ini at the root of your tests directory https://pytest.org/latest/customize.html

Answer (score 62, accepted):

By convention it searches for

> Test prefixed test classes (without an **init** method)

eg.

```
# content of test_class.py
class TestClass:
    def test_one(self):
        x = "this"
        assert 'h' in x

    def test_two(self):
        x = "hello"
        assert hasattr(x, 'check')

    # this works too
    @staticmethod
    def test_three():
        pass

    # this doesn't work
    #@classmethod
    #def test_three(cls):
    #    pass
```

See the docs:

- [Group multiple tests in a class](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/getting-started.html#group-multiple-tests-in-a-class)
- [Conventions for Python test discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/explanation/goodpractices.html#test-discovery)

Comment: I'd like to add, that these need to be regular methods, `@staticmethod` will not be found

Comment: new [link to doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/reorganize-docs/new-docs/user/naming_conventions.html)

Comment: Make sure there are no imports that are not installed, that'll cause files to be skipped

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer is not incorrect, but it is incomplete. Also, the link it contains to the documentation no longer works, nor does the updated link in the a comment on that answer.

The current documentation can now be found [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/goodpractices.html#test-discovery).  The relevant bits of that doc are:

> - ...
> - In those directories, search for ***test_*.py*** or ****_test.py*** files, imported by their test package name.
> - From those files, collect test items:
>
>   - ...
>   - ***test*** prefixed test functions or methods inside ***Test*** prefixed test classes (without an ***__init__*** method)

The key bit that is missing in the accepted answer is that not only must the class name start with ***Test*** and not have an ***__init__*** method, but also, the name of the file containing the class ***MUST*** be of one of the forms ***test_*.py*** or ****_test.py***.

Where I got tripped up here, and I assume many others will too, is that I generally name my Python source files containing only a class definition to directly mirror the name of the class.  So if my class is named ***MyClass***, I normally put its code in a file named ***MyClass.py***.  I then put test code for my class in a file named ***TestMyClass.py***.  This won't work with PyTest.  To let PyTest do its thing with my test class, I need to name the file for this class ***test_MyClass.py*** or ***MyClass_test.py***.  I chose the last form so that I generally add a '***_test***' suffix to the file names I'd otherwise choose that need to be named so that PyTest will parse them looking for tests.

Comment: my test class has  an `__init__()` method. Why is it  discriminated against?

Comment: I have no idea.  I just forwarded along what the documentation says.

Comment: it was same issue for me I had missed a <__init__.py> in the subfolder.

Comment: This i *very* accurate. I had to change name from `test.py` to `_test.py` in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

pytest discovers all tests following its Conventions for Python test discovery, so it finds both test_ prefixed functions. There is no need to subclass anything, but make sure to prefix your class with Test otherwise the class will be skipped. We can simply run the module by passing its filename:

Comment: This does not appear to add anything beyond what the existing answers say. Please don't repeat answers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34304409)